# How do I read the attribute data associated with my SHP?

Tags: shapefile, c#, .net, dotspatial

I'm using DotSpatial to aid in processing some geospatial data. I'm using the code below to determine if a point (lat/lon location) is within a polygon contained in the SHP. If the point is in a polygon, I want some of the attributes stored in the DBF associated with the polygon. How do I access the attribute data?

```
// Reproject the strange shapefile so that it is in latitude/longitude coordinates
wierdShapefile.Reproject(DotSpatial.Projections.KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984);

// Define the WGS84 Lat Lon point to test
Coordinate test = new Coordinate(longitude, latitude);

foreach (Feature f in wierdShapefile.Features)
{
    Polygon pg = f.BasicGeometry as Polygon;
    if (pg != null)
    {
        if (pg.Contains(new Point(test)))
        {
            ******************************************
            *** Need to access attribute data here ***
            ******************************************

            // If the point is inside one of the polygon features
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // If you have a multi-part polygon then this should also handle holes I think
        MultiPolygon polygons = f.BasicGeometry as MultiPolygon;
        if (polygons.Contains(new Point(test)))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to access the corresponding row in the feature class data table, with:

f.dataRow

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good answer should include an explanation about where and how to use the suggested solution, and details on how it solves the problem.  Please **[edit]** your answer to include this information.